Class member Field doesn't change value
How can it be that a simple public class member (bool _ValueChanged) doesn't update when trying to set it to true. It forever remains "false", no matter how I try to set it.
[Edit:] This code is a Rhino3D Grasshopper program calling into my C# Framework Dll which is wrapping the entire Rhino3D API.
Fig. 1). Attempting to set a property value = true, but 2). after setting the member, the value is still false(!)

After this I have an Debug.Assert which reports the same - the IsValueChanged attribute is still false.
[Addendum 1]: And the code below is also happening just after the attempt to set the IsValueChanged attribute (still "false"):

< scratching head >
[Addendum 2]: CenterAxis is a property, presenting the m_CenterAxis which is a pointer to a C# class in a DLL(my Co_Framework) which contains a Rhino3D property of type Line. Line is a struct. The Rhino API: mcneel.github.io/rhinocommon-api-docs/api/RhinoCommon/html/…
I also notice that when hovering over the attribute with the mouse, there's a little icon depicting a "lock". I guess that in this context it means that the inner field is "private"(?)
Is this refusal to change value only some phenomenon happening in debug mode, or what?
I have never seen anything like this before, and the whole program is just not working due to a number of properties/attributes behaving like this.
Any ideas about what could cause this strange behavior?
Using VS2022, Win10. I've done programming for over three decades, but I'm at loss...
//RIL

What type of program is this? Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc? Is your application multi-threaded?

Post your program code that we can run ourselves, otherwise we cannot help you.

Specifically a [mre]. Try starting with a new, empty program and add just enough code to reproduce the problem.

The padlock overlay indicates the member is private.

@gunr2171,@Dai, This is a Rhino3D Grasshopper program calling into my C# Framework Dll which is wrapping the entire Rhino3D API. Plain fields refusing to change, even when inspecting INSIDE the property just after the assignment (as in the picture above), still the field doesn't change. Why I'm even asking (without providing the entire framework, is if someone else has ever experienced something similar, and thus could give some pointers in which direction to search for clues? I hope that makes sense?

@NetMage, OK, thank you, for confirming the padlock as depicting "private".

"This is a Rhino3D Grasshopper program calling into my C# Framework Dll" - that information should be in the question as well. No, this isn't normal. It's very hard to suggest next steps with only very partial information.

I added the info about the wrapping of the Rhino3D - GrassHopper API to the original post. The properties and attribute are inside a plain C# class.

"The properties and attribute are inside a plain C# class." - So can you reproduce the problem using that class but not in Rhino3D? (e.g. in a console app) If you log the results instead of just looking in the debugger, does that still demonstrate the problem?

I've thought of one thing that could explain it, potentially - what's the type of m_CenterAxis? Is it a class or a struct? And is m_CenterAxis a field or a property? (All of this would have been better as a [mcve] to start with...)

Got guests visiting...  I'll be back with a stripped-down example after the weekend.

@Jon Skeet, the CenterAxis itself is a property. The type of the m_CenterAxis  is a pointer to a C# class in a DLL containing a Rhino3D Line property. Line is a struct:
https://mcneel.github.io/rhinocommon-api-docs/api/RhinoCommon/html/T_Rhino_Geometry_Line.htm
Strange that C# simple types works fine, but not types from the RhinoCommon API. Worth mentioning is that not only Rhino structs (like Line, Point3d, Vector3d & Plane) causes this samt problem, but also Rhino classes, like Curve and Brep.
As said, I'll dig deeper into this and try to make a simple test case after the weekend.

I don't see any use of a CenterAxis member. It's not clear whether you really mean pointer, or just a normal C# reference. It's unclear where Line comes in. Hopefully when you've provided a repro, it'll all be significantly clearer.

I have now excluded the possibility that the property (observers/subscribers and notification) mechanisms are involved in this problem. As indicated, the problem ONLY appears when types from the RhinoCommon (API) is involved, but does not appear when wrapping std C# simple types. So, making a "small stripped down example" would have to include RhinoCommon (API), which requires a software licence. By commenting out every other prop./method wrapper (apart from the main property providing the value object (like a double or a Curve), the code runs fine == property impl. thus works. Digging deeper.
